# Domain name for Raspberry pi

Tags: linux, networking, router, dns, raspberry-pi

I've a network with a `router` (TP-LINK) which delivers internet to my PC and laptop. Recently, I got `raspberry pi` and would like to connect to via `ssh`. The fact that I'm aware how to set ssh connection to raspberry pi from laptop or PC but I'm wondering how to bind specific **`domain`** to my raspberry pi's `ip adress`. For instance, I'would like ssh **hostname@domain_** from PC or my laptop instead of entering it's ip adress of pi in my home network to ssh. Can you help me?

P.S. 
There is a situation, where dynamic ip address allocated to my pi every time I reconnect it to network.

Comment: If you don't have a DNS server setup, then you have no system to bind IP's to host names.  Give you Pi a static IP, and edit your HOSTS file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get my home machines to connect to each other via hostname?](http://superuser.com/questions/121236/how-can-i-get-my-home-machines-to-connect-to-each-other-via-hostname), http://superuser.com/questions/45789/running-dns-locally-for-home-network?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use the simpler command to establish ssh connection you can try to make a `config` file:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host pi4
  HostName 192.168.88.252
  User ak
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa

Host pi3
  HostName 192.168.88.248
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
```

And If you want to use domain names, you must assign them to your raspberry somehow. I use MikroTik, so I just add static DNS records:

```
[admin@MikroTik] > ip dns static print
Flags: D - dynamic, X - disabled
 #    NAME                   REGEXP                  ADDRESS                                                  TTL
 0    router.lan                                     192.168.88.1                                             1d
 1    pi4.local                                      192.168.88.252                                           1d
 2    pi3.local                                      192.168.88.248                                           1d
```

As an alternative, you can edit `hosts` file on your machine like that:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       pi4

192.168.88.252  pi4.local
192.168.88.248  pi3.local
```

P.S But of course, you need to make sure that your raspberry have a static IP address if you don`t want to edit all this configs every time

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create an alias in Terminal to connect you via SSH automatically?

alias pi="ssh root@10.0.0.X"

So in future, just type in 'pi' in terminal and it will send the command.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But, I would like to experience some ip to domain bind :)

Comment: In that case use BIND or the host function in Linux

Answer (score 0):

As It is behind your router and I suppose you use NAT. One way to achieve this is to use a dns server with a dhcp server.
The point is to create in your dhcp a static lease for your raspbery and add this to your dns.
Other strategy is to add the raspberry in your host and to configure it with a static ip :)

Comment: This answer is a bit too brief. Can you explain *how* to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You could use [No-Ip](http://www.noip.com/)

You will an account (which is free) and select a domain.