# DNS Server on Windows

Tags: dns, ftp

Can anyone help me?

I have successfully hosted a ftp server at my pc on my pc ip address 192.168.1.101

Now i want to have Domain name of **FTP** so that if i type in the browser **ftp://FTP**, they will be able to visit the ftp server on my PC?

Regards

Darknet99

Comment: Who's "They"?  People on your LAN, people on the Internet? Please specify more detail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get my home machines to connect to each other via hostname?](http://superuser.com/questions/121236/how-can-i-get-my-home-machines-to-connect-to-each-other-via-hostname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took away my original answer.

If you want them to type "ftp://ftp" and get to your local ftp server, then all you need to do is change the computer name from whatever it is now, to FTP.

Answer (score 0):

At first, 192.168.1.101 is a local ip address (dynamic one), to find out your real ip address search "find my ip" on google. That will be your static ip address. But most of the ISP (internet service providers) change this static ip address, so that the users will not be able to host a site (Because they will charge you more for allocating you a static ip address).

Second point- If you manage to host a site at your static ip address, you can find the relevant information [here](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/setting-up-a-ftp-server-on-your-home-computer/) or you can skip through it and claim a namespace (http://www.noip.com/)

Comment: I WANT ONLY IN LOCAL AREA!!! WHY ARE YOU GOING TO ISPs AND REMOTE INTERNET CONNECTIVITY???

Comment: There is lot of ambiguity in your question, drawing the questions from different directions.